# Snakemake checkpoint (exited with non-zero exit code)

Tags: python, snakemake

I need to make a [checkpoint](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#data-dependent-conditional-execution) in Snakemake at the step where chromosomes are scattered to [call copy number variants with GATK](https://gatkforums.broadinstitute.org/gatk/discussion/11684#4.2):

```
rule all:
    input:
        'aggregated/chr1'

# step that gives non-zero exit code error
checkpoint scattering:
    input:
        interval = 'gcfiltered_{chr}.interval_list'
    output:
        directory('scatter_{chr}')
    shell:
        'mkdir -p {output} && '
        'gatk --java-options "-Xmx8G" IntervalListTools '
        '--INPUT {input.interval} '
        '--SUBDIVISION_MODE INTERVAL_COUNT '
        '--SCATTER_CONTENT 600 '
        '--OUTPUT {output}'

def aggregate_scatter(wildcards):
    checkpoint_output = checkpoints.scattering.get(**wildcards).output[0]
    return expand('scatter_{chr}/{i}/scattered.interval_list',
            chr=wildcards.chr,
            i=glob_wildcards(os.path.join(checkoint_output, '{i}/scattered.interval_list')).i)

# dummy rule to check if scattered files will be aggregated:
rule aggregate:
    input:
        aggregate_scatter
    output:
        "aggregated/{chr}"
    shell:
        "cat {input} > {output}"
```

But the `scattering` rule fails. It gives an error `(exited with non-zero exit code)` and removes the output, although the output is produced correctly. I tried adding `|| true`, it did not work.

However, when I run the command outside of snakemake, it runs fine with 0 exit status:

```
mkdir -p scatter_chr1 && gatk --java-options "-Xmx8G" IntervalListTools --INPUT gcfiltered_chr1.interval_list --SUBDIVISION_MODE INTERVAL_COUNT --SCATTER_CONTENT 600 --OUTPUT scatter_chr1
echo $?
```

I use Snakemake 5.5.4 and GATK 4.1.2.0. Input file example (`gcfiltered_chr1.interval_list`):

```
@HD VN:1.6
@SQ SN:chr1 LN:122678785    UR:file:canFam3.fa  M5:e4671b339daa96b7f11eb0b68fd999d8
chr1    100000  100999  +   .
chr1    101000  101999  +   .
chr1    102000  102999  +   .
chr1    103000  103999  +   .
chr1    104000  104999  +   .
chr1    105000  105999  +   .
chr1    106000  106999  +   .
chr1    107000  107999  +   .
chr1    108000  108999  +   .
chr1    109000  109999  +   .
chr1    110000  110999  +   .
chr1    111000  111999  +   .
chr1    112000  112999  +   .
chr1    113000  113999  +   .
chr1    114000  114999  +   .
chr1    115000  115999  +   .
chr1    116000  116999  +   .
chr1    117000  117999  +   .
chr1    118000  118999  +   .
chr1    119000  119999  +   .
chr1    120000  120999  +   .
```

Comment: Try running snakemake with the [--printshellcmds](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executable.html#OUTPUT) option, and try running that command?

Comment: I have done that. The command is in the post `mkdir -p scatter_chr1 && gatk...` It runs fine with 0 exit status.

Comment: Ok I was expecting some mismatch between what you thought it executed and what it actually did. I'm afraid I am at a loss as well. Does it also fail with just the mkdir command?

Comment: Thanks for your effort. It seems to be a bug of Snakemake v5. I installed Snakemake 4.3.1 and use `dynamic()` instead of `checkpoint` and everything works fine. I will stay on Snakemake v4 for now.